# JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor without gitignore

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

The Hibernate `org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor`, that is one of my Eclipse Annotation Processors, is putting the generated classes into `.gitignore`. How to change this behaviour? I need them to be commited to git.

Comment: An annotation processor knows nothing about `.gitignore`. What you put in your `.gitignore` is down to you, and likely was there before any use of any annotation processor. If you can demonstrate that an annotation processor MODIFIES that file then you should report a bug on that software

Comment: You're right - it has been a setting in the Eclipse preferences - "Automatically ignore derived resources by adding them to .gitignore"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a setting in the Eclipse preferences - "Automatically ignore derived resources by adding them to .gitignore" - if this isn't checked, the metamodel classes aren't put into .gitignore.